# What is the use of a convection broiler?

Tags: equipment, convection

My oven has a convection broil setting. Why? Under what circumstances is it useful to have a breeze blowing over food under the broiler?

Comment: Upvoted. I wonder this myself.  A broiler relies on radiation rather than convection, so why bother blowing the air around in the oven when you're broiling?  I'd love to know if there are any practical reasons to do that.

Comment: Maybe if you're dehydrating something? Especially something you don't mind toasting a bit?  That's the benefit I thought of, anyway, the airflow would draw off moisture quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You might be warming something under the dish you are broiling

Comment: ... under what? You're an old-timer here; surely you can come up with a better/clearer answer than this.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Under the main dish be broiled.  Clearly you should be able to figure that out.  Cheers - I don't retaliate.

Comment: ... retaliate? For downvoting? Wasn't me; apparently two other people thought this was a poor answer.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Cool, not trying into a fight.

Comment: I read _warNing_ and thought it's a joke that I really do not get. But it makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 0):

With large roasts (I'm talking bone in 20lb to 40lb) it could be useful. Although the meat would have to be tenderized and probably cooked at lower temperatures first. But it would ensure that the meat remained moist at a higher temperature while crisping.